# Converting an AutoCloseable, Iterable class into a Stream

Tags: java-stream, autocloseable

`StreamSupport.stream()` can create a `Stream` from an `Iterable`, but what if the class implements `Iterable` and `AutoCloseable`?  Is it possible to convert that class to a `Stream` and construct it within a try-with-resources block?

```java
public class NonWorkingExample {
    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        // this won't call MyCursor.close()
        try (Stream<String> stream = StreamSupport.stream(new MyCursor().spliterator(), false)) {
            stream.forEach(System.out::println);
        }
    }

    private static class MyCursor implements AutoCloseable, Iterable<String> {
        public void close() throws Exception {
            System.out.println("close");
        }

        public Iterator<String> iterator() {
            List<String> items = new ArrayList<>();
            items.add("foo");
            items.add("bar");
            items.add("baz");
            return items.iterator();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [stated in the javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/BaseStream.html#onClose(java.lang.Runnable)), `BaseStream.onClose()` "Returns an equivalent stream with an additional close handler":

```java
public class WorkingExample {
    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        MyCursor cursor = new MyCursor();
        try (Stream<String> stream = StreamSupport.stream(cursor.spliterator(), false)
                                                  .onClose(cursor::close)) {
            stream.forEach(System.out::println);
        }
    }
}
```

will call `MyCursor.close()` as desired.